# Symfony add query in url doesn't work if there is no slash after domain prefix

Tags: symfony

I try to add a query in my url like this :

```
"ajax": "{{  path("ndd_array",{"action":"all" }) }}"
```

and get it with :

```
 $request->query->get('action') == 'all'
```

that give me that url :

```
http://myurl?action=all
```

but the 'action=all'is deleted if i have no slash like this :

```
http://myurl/?action=all
```

and if i add this slash, my route is not found, and i don't want modify my route, its possible to do this without slash ?

My controller code :

```
    public function boTableauAction(Request $request)
{

    if ( $request->query->get('action') == 'all' ) {
        return "ok";
    } else {
        return "nok;
    }
}
```

Edit : i have this problem when i use a prefix in route like this :

```
test:
    resource: "@test/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix: /{_locale}/test
    requirements:
    _locale: fr|en|fr_FR|en_EN
```

if i delete prefix and requirements its ok, why ?

edit2 : the problem is "/{_locale}/" if i have just "/test" that work, i don't understand why.

Comment: the 'action=all'is deleted, how? where ?

Comment: i don't know how is delete, that's i don't understand.
For example, for test, i enter in my navigator that url : http://dev-surveillance.safebrands.com/fr_FR/surveillance/bo/veille-ndd/ajax/tableau?action=all
And when i load the page action=all is delete and i have  just http://dev-surveillance.safebrands.com/fr_FR/surveillance/bo/veille-ndd/ajax/tableau

Comment: Show your controller code.

Comment: i add it in my post

Comment: No you can't do that without adding the slash. Why you can't modify the route?

Comment: i can modify the route, but i just prefere don't do this, but if it  is the only solution i will do.

And i have try on a other project the same action with url?action=all that work ... so i think the problem come to config no ?